# Kivy error - "Unable to get a window, abort"

Tags: python, window, kivy, x11, sdl-2

I installed kivy on my Raspberry pi3, where i run a python program that already works on another pi3.

I now am trying to install the same thing on this second pi, and it doesn't work...maybe I forgot something, but i think i did all the same steps as before..

kivy is well installed indeed, as other packages for the python program.

here below the error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python pi4.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-01-19_4.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04) 
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
egl_rpi - TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 817, in __init__
    super(WindowBase, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 273, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__ (/tmp/pip-IRRRCt-build/kivy/_event.c:5375)
  File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 423, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (/tmp/pip-IRRRCt-build/kivy/properties.c:5171)
  File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 1416, in kivy.properties.AliasProperty.set (/tmp/pip-IRRRCt-build/kivy/properties.c:23280)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 701, in _set_top
    self._set_window_pos(pos[0], value)

sdl2 - RuntimeError: Couldn't find matching GLX visual
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 139, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 841, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 263, in create_window
    self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 142, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (/tmp/pip-IRRRCt-build/kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:2458)
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 57, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die (/tmp/pip-IRRRCt-build/kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:1569)

x11 - ImportError: No module named window_x11
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: please note that i tried all the documented steps for workaround: uninstall/reinstall kivy, install libsdl2, and various others...   only thing i didnt try was to install in a virtualenv since it looks complicated. thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to fix this for now by running

```
sudo apt-get install \ 
    libsdl2-2.0-0 \ 
    libsdl2-image-2.0-0 \ 
    libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 \ 
    libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0
```

Comment: i'll try and let you know, I think i did this before and didn't work but will check again as I am back to the lab.  thanks!